# shell script + match MAJOR and CRITICAL strings from log file

Tags: shell, shell-scripting, sed, awk, ksh

I need to match lines that have MAJOR and CRITICAL strings

that comes after the word ERROR:< any integer number >

please advice how to do that with one awk or sed command?

```
  more HW_Log.txt



 CHK_HW             ERROR:0  INFO         self_monitor     Verifying HW machine 
 CHK_HW             ERROR:1  MAJOR        self_monitor     Verifying HW machine 
 CHK_HW             ERROR:1  CRITICAL     self_monitor     Verifying HW machine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `grep` like:

```
$ grep "ERROR:[0-9]*  \(CRITICAL\|MAJOR\)" /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` command:

```
awk '/ERROR\:[0-9]+[ \t]+(CRITICAL|MAJOR)/ {print}' path_to_file
```

`sed` command:

```
sed -ne '/ERROR\:[0-9]\+[ \t]\+\(CRITICAL\|MAJOR\)/p' path_to_file
```

`awk` description:

```
 '/ERROR\:[0-9]+[ \t]+(CRITICAL|MAJOR)/ {print}'
  ^                                     ^
  regexp                                command
```

- [0-9]+ - one or more digits
- [ \t]+ - one or more space and tab
- (CRITICAL|MAJOR) - "CRITICAL" or "MAJOR"
- print - print line

`sed` description:

```
   -n, --quiet, --silent
          suppress automatic printing of pattern space

   -e script, --expression=script
          add the script to the commands to be executed

 '/ERROR\:[0-9]\+[ \t]\+\(CRITICAL\|MAJOR\)/p' 
 ^                                          ^
 regexp                                     command
```

- [0-9]\+ - one or more digits
- [ \t]\+ - one or more space and tab
- \(CRITICAL\|MAJOR\) - "CRITICAL" or "MAJOR"
- p - print line

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in awk:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^ERROR:[[:digit:]]+/ && $3 ~ /^(MAJOR|CRITICAL)/' HW_Log.txt
```

This looks for the strings only in the fields indicated so it would ignore them if they appeared elsewhere in the line. It relies on the default behavior of awk to print matched lines (that's why there's no explicit `print` statement). It depends on no spaces or tabs appearing within the first three fields.